# Abrir input a partir de icono font awesome

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, font-awesome

Lo que pasa es que quiero que al presionar el icono de fa fa-paperclip me abra la ventana para escoger que archivos deseo adjuntar.

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
<html>

<head>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<a href = "#"><i class = "fa fa-paperclip"></i></a>

Que al dar click en el icono me abra el input file: 
<input type = "file">



</body>

</html>
```

Saludos.

Este fue el resultado:

function abrir() {

var file = document.getElementById("file").click();

}

```
  <i class = "fa fa-paperclip fa-2x text-blue" style = "cursor: pointer;" onclick="abrir()"></i>

  <input id = "file" type="file" style = "display: none;">
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar JS para llamar el evento del input:

```js
$("i").click(function () {
  $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
});

$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).siblings('span').text(val);
})
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

.fa {
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> Clic en el ícono para subir
  <input type="file">



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias tu respuesta junto con la otra me ayudo a resolver mi problema, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar un id al input y llamar al evento `click` asi:

```js
function abrir() {
  var file = document.getElementById("file").click();
  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<a href = "#"><i class = "fa fa-paperclip" onclick="abrir()"></i></a>

Que al dar click en el icono me abra el input file: 
<input id="file" type = "file">



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias tu respuesta junto con la otra me ayudo a resolver mi problema, saludos.